# C++ wxWidgets MVC structure

Tags: c++, visual-studio, model-view-controller, wxwidgets

I am new to wxWidgets. I am creating a C++ application in Visual Studio, with a single application window containing several frames. I intend to implement the model-view-controller architecture, with folders for each of model, view and controller. I am defining some classes and functions in the controller folder.

**1)** Should I `#include` these in order to use them in the main file? Or use namespaces?

**2)** How do I work with namespaces defined in different directories.

I am a .NET developer, so quite new to C++.

Comment: namespaces and using statements are completely different in C++ than C#.

Comment: I would recommend to get something going first, and only later worrying about implementing MVC or MVP patterns in your application. You can refactor that later. Especially if you are new to wxWidgets.